# In-order traversal BST

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, tostring, inorder

I want my output to come out as follows:

> (E: HAR@litfried L:  R: (E: HAR@tika L: (E: HAR@LynConway L:  R: ) R: ) ). I've tried everything possible but I keep getting this instead. (E: HAR@litfried L:  R: (E: HAR@tika L:  R: (E: HAR@LynConway L:  R: ) ) ).

Here is my code:

```
public class BST {
    private BSTNode root;

    public BST(){
        root = null;
    }

    public void insertColleague(Colleague c) {
        BSTNode node = new BSTNode(c);
        if (root == null){
            root = node;
        }else {
            insertColleague(root, node);
        }

    }

    private void insertColleague(BSTNode currNode, BSTNode node) {
        if(currNode.getC().getUserName().compareTo(root.getC().getUserName())<0){
            if (currNode.getL() == null){
                currNode.setL(node);
            } else {
                insertColleague(currNode.getL(), node);
            }
        } else{
            if (currNode.getR() == null){
                currNode.setR(node);
            }else {
                insertColleague(currNode.getR(), node);
            }
        }

    }

    public void printInOrder() {
        printInOrderRecursive(root);
        //System.out.print("L: ");
        //System.out.println("R: <null>)");
    }

    private void printInOrderRecursive(BSTNode current) {
        if (current == null) {
            System.out.print("<null>");
            return;
        }
        System.out.print("(E: " + current.getC().getUserName() + " ");
        System.out.print("L: ");
        printInOrderRecursive(current.getL());
        System.out.print(" R: ");
        printInOrderRecursive(current.getR());
        System.out.print(")");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Where is your code feeding those values? How come your code prints "<null>" and you don't have that in your output? You have not presented the code with which the problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired output, you should modify the insertColleague method to compare the usernames in a case-insensitive manner. Instead of using compareTo, use compareToIgnoreCase when comparing the usernames.
`if(currNode.getC().getUserName().compareToIgnoreCase(root.getC().getUserName()) < 0)`

You also need to update the printInOrder method to print the output in the desired format. Print the result in the order of (E: username L: (left subtree) R: (right subtree)) for each node in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void insertColleague(Colleague c) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new BSTNode(c);
    } else{
        insertCRecurse(root, c);
    }
}

//recursively insert node function
private void insertCRecurse(BSTNode currNode, Colleague c) {
    if (c.getUserName().compareToIgnoreCase(currNode.getC().getUserName())<1){
        if (currNode.getL() != null){
            insertCRecurse(currNode.getL(), c);
        } else{
            currNode.setL(new BSTNode(c));
        }
    }else {
        if (currNode.getR() !=null){
            insertCRecurse(currNode.getR(), c);
        } else{
            currNode.setR(new BSTNode(c));
        }
    }

}

//traverse the tree in-order
public void printInOrder() {
    printInOrderRecursive(root);
}

private void printInOrderRecursive(BSTNode current) {
    if (current == null) {
        System.out.print("<null>");
        return;
    }
    System.out.print("(E: " + current.getC().getUserName() + " ");
    System.out.print("L: ");
    printInOrderRecursive(current.getL());
    System.out.print(" R: ");
    printInOrderRecursive(current.getR());
    System.out.print(")");
}
```

Comment: I have solve the problem. The reason why was because I was recursing from the leftmost (compareTo()<0) subtree first instead of recursing from right(compareTo()<1)